# Change selected item on Material drop down menu

Tags: android, kotlin, material-components-android

I'm using two [material drop down menu](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Menu.md#exposed-dropdown-menus) with diferent prices listed, one for the minimum price and other for the maximum. I'm using this listener to get the selected Item: (minPrice and maxPrice are TextInputLayout)

```
(minPrice.editText as AutoCompleteTextView).onItemClickListener =
    OnItemClickListener { adapterView, view, position, id ->
        val selectedValue: String? = adapter.getItem(position)
    }

(maxPrice.editText as AutoCompleteTextView).onItemClickListener =
    OnItemClickListener { adapterView, view, position, id ->
        val selectedValue: String? = adapter2.getItem(position)
    }
```

But I also want to, for example, if the user selected 10k$ for the minimum, then if the user select less than 10k$ as maximum, change it to the minimum. Like this: if(maximum < minimum) maximum = minimum

The problem is that I don't know how to change the selected value. I've tried to do this: (priceMaxItems is the list of items)

```
if(priceMaxItems[maxPrice.editText?.text.toString()]!! priceMinItems[minPrice.editText?.text.toString()]!!) {
    maxPrice.editText?.text  = minPrice.editText?.text
}
```

But if I do this, the drop down menu will only show the only item than matches, it's like someone typed the number and not if someone selected the item.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your question but i got your aim to set maxPrice editText value to be minPrice.

this code will be confusing.

```
maxPrice.editText?.text  = minPrice.editText?.text
```

try to get the minPrice and set it to maxPrice
like :

```
val minP = minPrice.editText?.text
maxPrice.editText?.text = minP
```

Comment: but then it [only shows the item of the list that matches](https://i.imgur.com/ixyIszs.png), so now the user can't change the price